# How to close a .txt file as it opens

Tags: java, file

Need a program written in Java to close a .txt file as it opens (so that the user can, hopefully, not see it). How would I go about closing a .txt file as soon as it opens?

The alternatives to this way is to open the file on the secondary monitor or replace the text in the file instantly so the user cannot see this.

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. What do you mean by "Close a file as it opens so the user won't see it"?

Comment: So that when the file is automatically opened by another program, the file should be exited (or not opened at all)

Comment: Are you asking for a program which detects if a file is opened at any given time and then closes it? That's a bit complicated don't you think?

Comment: Yeah, or just opens all text files on the 2nd monitor?

Comment: Do you want to close every opened `.txt` file or a specific file name?

Comment: It can close every .txt file opened as this program will only be open when this is wanted to be used.

Comment: One solution is to store the content of everything in a variable (which wipes out every single other file with read/write permission), and just put it back when the program closes.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question you want to intercept all requests, by any program running in a computer, to open any text file, and prevent that file from being accessed.

This is categorically beyond the capabilities of anything you can do in Java, or any "user-space" environment.  Anything of this type would have to be done as part of the operating system, operating in privileged mode, and working with the filesystem drivers.

This could probably be done but would be operating-system specific and likely need to be written in C++ or assembler. Also it would require specific user action to be installed and would require superuser or administrator privileges.

This is not something within reach of a developer without significant OS kernel experience.

Sounds like you are trying to write ransomware?